# Strange $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{(1-e^x)^2\over (1-x^2)^2}dx\approx0.999976$

Tags: calculus

To  my wonder what would be the closed form for this integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{(1-e^x)^2\over (1-x^2)^2}dx$ it has an approximate value of strangely $\approx0.999976 ...?$

we can start off by making a simple substitution 
$(x=\sin y, dx=\cos y)$

$$\int_{0}^{\arcsin(\pi/4)}\sec^3 y(1-e^{\sin y})^2dy\tag1$$

$$\int_{0}^{\arcsin(\pi/4)}\sec^3 y-2\sec ^3ye^{\sin y}+\sec^3ye^{2\sin y}dy\tag2$$

$$\int_{0}^{\arcsin(\pi/4)}\sec^3 ydy-\int_{0}^{\arcsin(\pi/4)}2\sec ^3ye^{\sin y}+\sec^3ye^{2\sin y}dy\tag3$$

using integration by part $$\int_{0}^{\arcsin(\pi/4)}\sec^3 ydy$$ gives

$0.5\left(\tan x\sec x-\ln\left[\cos(x/2)-\sin(x/2)\right]+\ln[\cos(x/2)+\sin(x/2)]\right)+K$ and putting the limit that would be a quite labour job.

May be there is another way of dealing with this problem.

Comment: what is "strange" here?

Comment: There are numbers which are called "almost integers". They don't have any special significance in mathematics, but if you are interested here's the links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_integer and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostInteger.html

Answer (score 2):

The antiderivative can be computed
$$I=\int{(1-e^x)^2\over (1-x^2)^2}\,dx$$ $$4I=\frac{2 \left(1-e^x\right)^2 x}{1-x^2}+\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x} \right)+\frac{-4 e \text{Ei}(x+1)+e^4 \text{Ei}(2 x-2)+3 \text{Ei}(2 x+2)}{e^2}$$ where appears the exponential integral function.

I shall not write the expression of the definite integral which effectively is evaluated as  $0.99997570282872060195$

You could get the antiderivative using Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 1):

The integral is tedious, but it's just a sum of much easier integrals, and it makes sense to reduce the problem that way:

$$(1-e^x)^2=1-2e^x+e^{2x}$$

$$\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2}=\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1}{1-x} +\frac{1}{1+x}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1}{1-x} +\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\right)$$

Thus, we need to find a $12$ different integrals (which then all need to be multiplied by $1/4$):

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{dx}{1-x}=-\int_1^{1-\pi/4} \frac{dy}{y}=-\ln \left(1-\frac{\pi}{4} \right)$$

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{dx}{1+x}=\int_1^{1+\pi/4} \frac{dy}{y}=\ln \left(1+\frac{\pi}{4} \right)$$

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{dx}{(1-x)^2}=-\int_1^{1-\pi/4} \frac{dy}{y^2}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{\pi}{4} }-1$$

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}=\int_1^{1+\pi/4} \frac{dy}{y^2}=1-\frac{1}{1+\frac{\pi}{4} }$$

---

Next four integrals need additionally to be multiplied by $-2$:

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{e^x dx}{1-x}=-e \int_1^{1-\pi/4} \frac{e^{-y}dy}{y}= e \left(\text{Ei} \left(-1 \right)-\text{Ei} \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-1 \right) \right)$$

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{e^xdx}{1+x}=\frac{1}{e}\int_1^{1+\pi/4} \frac{e^y dy}{y}=\frac{1}{e} \left(\text{Ei} \left(1+\frac{\pi}{4} \right)-\text{Ei} \left(1 \right) \right)$$

The following two integrals use these properties of the exponential integral:

$$\frac{d}{dy} \text{Ei}(-y)=\frac{e^{-y}}{y}$$

$$\frac{d}{dy} \text{Ei}(y)=\frac{e^{y}}{y}$$

---

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{e^xdx}{(1-x)^2}=-e\int_1^{1-\pi/4} \frac{e^{-y}dy}{y^2}= e \left(\text{Ei} \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-1 \right)-\text{Ei} \left(-1 \right) \right)+ \frac{e^{\pi/4}}{1-\frac{\pi}{4}} - 1  $$

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{e^xdx}{(1+x)^2}=\frac{1}{e}\int_1^{1+\pi/4} \frac{e^ydy}{y^2}=\frac{1}{e} \left(\text{Ei} \left(1+\frac{\pi}{4} \right)-\text{Ei} \left(1 \right) \right)+1- \frac{e^{\pi/4}}{1+\frac{\pi}{4}}  $$

---

Last four integrals reduce to the previous four, with the proper change of variable:

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{e^{2x} dx}{1-x}=-e^2 \int_1^{1-\pi/4} \frac{e^{-2y}dy}{y}= e^2 \left(\text{Ei} \left(-2 \right)-\text{Ei} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2 \right) \right)$$

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{e^{2x}dx}{1+x}=\frac{1}{e^2}\int_1^{1+\pi/4} \frac{e^{2y} dy}{y}=\frac{1}{e^2} \left(\text{Ei} \left(2+\frac{\pi}{2} \right)-\text{Ei} \left(2 \right) \right)$$

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{e^{2x}dx}{(1-x)^2}=-e^2 \int_1^{1-\pi/4} \frac{e^{-2y}dy}{y^2}= e^2 \left(2 \text{Ei} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2 \right)-2 \text{Ei} \left(-2 \right) \right)+ \frac{e^{\pi/2}}{1-\frac{\pi}{4}} - 1  $$

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{e^{2x}dx}{(1+x)^2}=\frac{1}{e^2}\int_1^{1+\pi/4} \frac{e^{2y}dy}{y^2}=\frac{1}{e^2} \left(2 \text{Ei} \left(2+\frac{\pi}{2} \right)-2 \text{Ei} \left(2 \right) \right)+1- \frac{e^{\pi/2}}{1+\frac{\pi}{4}}  $$

---

Now we add all 12 results and, with some simplifications, obtain:

> $$4I=\ln \left(\frac{4+\pi}{4-\pi} \right)+\frac{8\pi (1-e^{\pi/4})^2}{16-\pi^2}- \frac{4}{e} \left(\text{Ei} \left(1+\frac{\pi}{4} \right)-\text{Ei} \left(1 \right) \right)+ \\ +  e^2 \left( \text{Ei} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2 \right)- \text{Ei} \left(-2 \right) \right)+\frac{3}{e^2} \left(\text{Ei} \left(2+\frac{\pi}{2} \right)-\text{Ei} \left(2 \right) \right) = \\ =3.9999028113148824 \approx 4$$

Wolfram Alpha doesn't give any nice simplification for the above expression, which is why I'm sure the numerical value is just a coincidence.